# Is it possible to hide or delete the new Toolbar in 13.1?

Tags: front-end, toolbar

Is it possible to delete or hide the new toolbar in 13.1?  How?  It's a great resource, however, for my applications, it's not very useful. It's also glitching out making it impossible to use on most of my programs.  I tried clearing the dockedcells but that doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Comment: Use the menu `Mathematica | Preferences | Interface | General Settings` and uncheck `Show default toolbar in standard notebooks`

Comment: How is it glitching out?  It's supposed to be pretty robust

Comment: @QuantumDot All of the button images turn into down arrows every once in a while making them fairly useless unless you have them memorized

Comment: Are you able to recreate this problem?  I am looking to build my own toolbar modeled after this one.  But now with this bug, I'm having second thoughts

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just uncheck the Show default toolbar in standard notebooks in Edit ⊳ Preferences ⊳ Interface ⊳ General Settings:

[image]

Comment: Well, I feel pretty dumb right now.  lol. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

for making this change only for the current notebook and not permanent using the options, you can just do windows->toolbar as follows and uncheck default.

[image]