# Is it possible to programatically create new notebook without the default top Toolbar (the one introduced in 13.1)?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I know how this can be hide using [via the UI](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277179/is-it-possible-to-hide-or-delete-the-new-toolbar-in-13-1). But is there a way to create a New Notebook using `CreateDocument[{}]` that does not contain the toolbar?

Comment: `CreateDocument[{}, WindowToolbars -> {}]`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch It works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CreateDocument[{}, WindowToolbars -> {}]`